# For which $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x n^{\alpha} e^{-nx}$ a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ and $[0, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from a book in analysis.

I've got an approach to the problem, but I'm not sure how to tie everything together.

After thinking about it, I am able to show that the series does converge for all $x \geq 0$.

I tried to simply find where the series is uniformly convergent: the sup of the function will always occur at $x = 1/n$ on either of the intervals, and so the Weierstrass-M test shows that the sum of the sup-norm of the sequence is equal to

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{\alpha - 1} e^{-1}$$

Which is obviously convergent only when $\alpha < 0$.

Thus we see that on both $(0, \infty)$ and $[0, \infty]$ the series is uniformly convergent and thus continuous.

However, I'm not sure how to show that the function is / isn't continuous for $\alpha \geq 0$, on either of the intervals.

I would appreciate help with this problem!

Comment: Given any $\delta > 0$, the series is uniformly convergent on $[\delta,\infty)$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ (why?), hence is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ (why?).  If $\alpha > 0$, take $N \in \mathbb N_+$ and note that $S(\frac{1}{N}) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{N} n^\alpha e^{-n\frac{1}{N}} \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N} e^{-1} = e^{-1}$, but $S(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! I think I've almost got it. The only part I'm confused about Is why why we would need to consider uniform convergence on $[\delta, \infty]$, as opposed to just $(0,\infty)$. Because when using the Weierstrass-M test, I am still running into the same issue I described in the problem, where the sum of the sup-norm of the functions only converges when $\alpha < 0$. Could you give another hint about proving such uniform convergence on $[\delta, \infty)$?

Comment: The supremum of $n'$th term indeed occurs at $x = \frac{1}{n}$, but that point fails to be in $[\delta,\infty)$ for $n$ sufficiently large. You can proceed as follows; $x \mapsto x e^{-nx}$ has derivative $e^{-nx}(1 -nx)$, hence this function is decreasing for $x > \frac{1}{n}$. In particular, if $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$, then the supremum of $n'$th term on $[\delta,\infty)$ occurs at $\delta$, i.e. we can bound $\sum_{n=1}^\infty xn^a e^{-nx} \le \sum_{n=1}^N n^{a-1}e^{-1} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \delta n^a e^{-\delta n}$ and apply M-test.